# Scrape for Table with Limits

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, limit

There is a web site that has data on it that it pulls from an API. The max number of rows you can have per page is 100. If you were to check the API URL from page 1, 2, 3, etc they change each time. So far I have taken the same script each time and just switched out the URL but I then also have to save it in a different excel file every time or else it removes data.

I'd like to have a script to be able to pull all information from this table and then place them all into an excel on the same sheet without the values being overwritten.

The main page I'm using is http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?aggregate=0&report=daysbetweengames&reportType=game&dateFrom=2021-10-12&dateTo=2021-11-30&gameType=2&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=a_teamFullName,daysRest&page=0&pageSize=50 but please keep in mind that all the information on that page is being pulled from an API.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
url = ('https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/daysbetweengames? `isAggregate=false&isGame=true&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22teamFullName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22daysRest%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D,%7B%22property%22:%22teamId%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=500&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameDate%3C=%222021-11-30%2023%3A59%3A59%22%20and%20gameDate%3E=%222021-10-12%22%20and%20gameTypeId=2')`

resp = requests.get(url).text
resp = json.loads(resp)
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['data'])
df.to_excel('Master File.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Info')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see `start=...` in url - run it in `for`-loop with different values `0`, `100`, `200`, etc. in `start=...`

Comment: BTW: in requests you could all values after `?` put in code as normal list/dictonary and later use as `params` in `get(..., params=...)`

Comment: you can get directly `response.json()` instead of `response.text` with `json.load(...)`

Answer (score 0):

`url` has `start=...` - so you can use `for`-loop and replace this value `0`, `100`, `200`, etc. and run code for different urls, and `append()` to `DataFrame`

It can be simpler if you put all arguments from url (after char `?`) to dictionary and later run as `get(url, params=...)`

`requests` has `response.json` so it doesn't need `json.loads(response.text)`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# --- before loop ---

url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/daysbetweengames'

payload = {
    'isAggregate': 'false',
    'isGame': 'true',
    'start': 0,
    'limit': 100,
    'sort': '[{"property":"teamFullName","direction":"ASC"},{"property":"daysRest","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"teamId","direction":"ASC"}]',
    'factCayenneExp': 'gamesPlayed>=1',
    'cayenneExp': 'gameDate<="2021-11-30 23:59:59" and gameDate>="2021-10-12" and gameTypeId=2',
}

df = pd.DataFrame()

# --- loop ---

for start in range(0, 1000, 100):
    print('start:', start)
    
    payload['start'] = start
    
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

    data = response.json()

    df = df.append(data['data'], ignore_index=True)
    
# --- after loop ---

print(df)

df.to_excel('Master File.xlsx', sheet_name='Info')
```

Result:

```
     daysRest  faceoffWinPct    gameDate  ...  ties  timesShorthandedPerGame  wins
0           4        0.47169  2021-10-13  ...  None                      5.0     1
1           3        0.50847  2021-11-22  ...  None                      4.0     0
2           2        0.45762  2021-10-26  ...  None                      1.0     0
3           2        0.56666  2021-11-05  ...  None                      2.0     1
4           2        0.54716  2021-11-14  ...  None                      1.0     1
..        ...            ...         ...  ...   ...                      ...   ...
675         1        0.37209  2021-10-28  ...  None                      2.0     1
676         1        0.48000  2021-10-21  ...  None                      3.0     1
677         0        0.57692  2021-11-06  ...  None                      1.0     0
678         0        0.32727  2021-11-19  ...  None                      3.0     0
679         0        0.47169  2021-11-27  ...  None                      4.0     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it's helps a ton!

If I wanted to add this sheet to an existing Excel file as a brand new sheet within that file, how would I do that? 

I'm really new to all this so any insight you have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use Excel but probably you would have to open it in `append mode` - maybe it will need to use `ExcelWriter`. See examples in documentation [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) - there is example with  `ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a')`